# Faster way to write 20 remote files to a cache php

Tags: php, caching, json-api

I currently have this code. It fetches the json data file for each hour and the whole day's file from an api. It then caches the results for faster fetching. It currently takes ~10s to fetch all the files and use them (no caching), it takes ~1 to execute with a cache but it takes ~80s with the method below (with caching) when the cache is stale. There is other code obviously being run on this but this is the slow bit. `$this->hours` has 24 elements.

Is there a faster way to get the files & cache them?

```
/**
 * Get the weather data from forecast.io
 * @return array The overall weather data
 */
public function getData($kernelDir)
{
    $apiSite = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/';
    $url = $apiSite . $this->apiKey . '/' . $this->latitude . ',' . $this->longitude;

    if (!file_exists($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . '.' . $this->longitude))
    {
        $weatherFile = @file_get_contents($url);
        $fp = fopen($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . '.' . $this->longitude, 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, $weatherFile);
        fclose($fp);
    }
    else {
        $weatherFile = @file_get_contents($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . '.' . $this->longitude);
    }

    $this->weatherData['day'] = @json_decode($weatherFile, true);

    $this->getHours();

    foreach ($this->hours as $normal => $unixTimestamp)
    {
        $url = $apiSite . $this->apiKey . '/' . $this->latitude . ',' . $this->longitude . ',' . $unixTimestamp;

        if (!file_exists($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . '.' . $this->longitude . '.' . $unixTimestamp))
        {
            $weatherFile = @file_get_contents($url);
            $fp = fopen($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . '.' . $this->longitude . '.' . $unixTimestamp, 'w+');
            fwrite($fp, $weatherFile);
            fclose($fp);
        }
        else {
            $weatherFile = @file_get_contents($kernelDir . '/cache/api/' . $this->latitude . ',' . $this->longitude . ',' . $unixTimestamp);
        }

        $this->weatherData['time'][$normal] = @json_decode($weatherFile, true);
    }

    return $this->weatherData;
}
```

Comment: is a minute and a half once a day really to slow - i assume its done in the background

Comment: No, it's done on a request and I know it's really slow... hence the question to find a way to do it a lot faster....

Comment: but you say you cache it- so im confused

Comment: the approach i thought you where taking and i would do ,is retrieve in background (hourly\daily - what ever you need) then use the local files\db for data on request.

Comment: That's not possible, it would have to be done for every single longitude/latitude possible?